# MATLAB smooth transition between two polyfit curves

Tags: matlab, diff, curve-fitting

I got this data curve.
[image: Pic curve]
Because it's real data it's kind of *shaky*.
[image: shaky curve]

I want to differentiate the curve... this looks pretty ugly because of the shakyness.

So I went on and used `ployfit` and `polyval` to smooth the curve. As this doesn't resemble a ploynomal curve, I needed to split this curve in three and smooth them all separately and later fit them together again.

But `polyval` tend to *overdo* the edges... (the smooth one in red, the original in blue)
[image: zoom1]

so when I add them together I get non smooth junctions like this one here: (I know this is extreme, but it accurs always)
[image: zoom2]

when I later differentiate the curve, I get huge *errors* at the junctions:

[image: differentiate errors]

> any ideas to solve my problem?
>
> I do need a clean curve for calculations and so on...

### Edit

I implemented the comments:

here the results

[image]
[image]

`spline` isn't smooth enough for differentiation,
`Savitzky-Golay Filter` also not perfect

Comment: You might be better off using a [spline](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html).
Or, I actually did a similar thing with a multilinear function: you can write your own piecewise polynomial function while enforcing continuity at the waypoints, and you minimize the distance between your function and the data points with `fminsearch`

Comment: You could just differentiate it in the 3 separate sections, meaning you never get the large gradient from the jump... It appears you've got some crossover where you're plotting the two fits in the 4th image, you should probably keep the x regions distinct.

Comment: @Zep Looks like a good idea! Could you write this down as an answer as well?

Comment: @Wolfie you mean differentiate them on their own and then fit them together right? sounds nice... I'll try that too

Comment: You should take a look at the Savitzky–Golay filter, those filter is already implemented in matlab : `sgolayfilt`. The SG filter use a polynomial estimation based on x points for each points, it's look like the perfect deal for you.

Comment: I implemented your comments

Comment: If you are interested in the derivative, note that offsets do not play a role. Hence, you can add/ subtract constants piecewise to remove the jumps. The trick would be removing the jumps. Automatic treatment in flat regions this should be rather easy, in regions of high slope, you need to correct for the average slope.